# PSR-4 not finding Exceptions

Tags: php, exception, autoload

I have PSR 4 autoloading and it works just fine, but there is an issue with Exceptions. I want to put all my exceptions into a single file since they are all basically empty extensions of PHP standard exceptions with new names.

So I create the file `Exceptions.php` within the src/Project/Support folder. I added `namespace Project\Support\Exceptions;` to the top, but apparently now it can't find any of the exceptions. My IDE finds them just fine, but PHP tells me `Project\Support\Exceptions\ThingNotFoundException` does not exist.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: In your autoloader print out the file name, and compare it against your files. Also, make sure the class is named correctly. And if you are on Linux make sure the file is capitalized correctly. When autoloaders are unable to find classes/interfaces/etc. it is almost always that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Well, the Exceptions.php file holds multiple classes that should all be under the Exception namespace. i'd just rather not create a file for every single empty exception. How do i print out the file names?

Comment: This might not be possible. Won't the autoloader only check a file for a class if it matches the name / path? Something like that? It doesn't know that the Exception you're requesting is inside that overall Exception file.

Comment: This worked before, it suddenly stopped working which leads me to believe I did something. I just can't figure it out.